# OPENQUERY query stored in string fails with EXEC

Tags: sql, sql-server, openquery

I'm trying to pull back some data via a linked server that has 'Geography' fields present, consequntly I'm trying to use Open Query.
I'm also trying to pass in a variable...

Can anyone explain this:
This is my sql...

```
DECLARE @Sql VARCHAR(200)
DECLARE @tnum VARCHAR(20)= 'abc';
SET @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM NationalPolygon.dbo.Polygon WHERE TitleNumber = ''''' + @tnum + '''''';
SET @Sql = 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(mylinkedserver01, ''' + REPLACE(@Sql, '?', '''') + ''')'

SELECT @Sql;
EXEC @Sql;
```

If I select @Sql and run it, it works.
If I run the @Sql via EXEC it fails with:

```
Database 'SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(mylinkedserver01, 'SELECT * FROM NationalPolygon' does not exist. Make sure that the name is entered correctly.
```

Thanks
C

Comment: There are 2 different syntax forms for EXECUTE. One executes the query stored in a string - that requires parentheses around the string (or variable).

Answer (score 1):

You need to surround @Sql with brackets

```sql
EXEC (@Sql);
```

Comment: Ta, that's sorted it.